# Source root is duplicated in module ... error in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm working on a large Maven project in IntelliJ Idea. Java version is 8. When I build the project it fails with this output:

```
java Modules ACClient and FdsxClient must have the same language level because of cyclic dependencies between them
    In the *Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Project*
SDK value is 1.8 Oracle OpenJDK
Language level value is 8 - Lambdas, type annotations etc.
    In the *Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Modules*
```

Language level for ACClient is 8 - Lambdas, type annotations etc.  (as expected).
Language level for FdsxClient is 6 - @Override in interfaces (this is the problem).

So I change the wrong one but when I click the apply button an error dialog shows up.

> Source root
> 'C:\workspace\largeJavaProject_r\abacus\ACClient\src\main\java' is
> duplicated in module 'AbcClient'.

Rebuilding project and Maven -> Reload project does not help.

Comment: Does this question perhaps belong on StackOverflow? That is a programming-specific sister site. It depends on if this is a code issue or an application issue.

Comment: Could you share your Project? Or at least the screenshots of Project Structure -> Modules -> Sources with those two conflicting Modules selected?

Comment: I had something similar occur recently - ended up clearing the C:\Users\userprofile\.grade\caches folder out and then restarted IDEA. After it reimported the gradle project the duplicate modules disappeared inside idea.

Comment: Have some of you already resolved this issue? I'm still getting it and this is annoying :(